# Computing the time elapsed in Java

Tags: java, timer

Is `javax.swing.Timer timer;` enough for computing the time elapsed? I'm doing a Tetris project that also calculates the time it took for the player to play the game. In the `play` method,

```
public void play() {
        reset();
        onPlay = true;
        Thread thread = new Thread(new Game());
        thread.start();
        rightPanel.setPlayButtonEnable(false);
        rightPanel.setPause(true);
        rightPanel.setStop(true);
        playItem.setEnabled(false);
        pauseItem.setEnabled(true);
        stopItem.setEnabled(true);
        setBlockColorItem.setEnabled(false);
        setBGColorItem.setEnabled(false);
        rightPanel.requestFocus();
        //time.start();
        //timeElapsed = System.currentTimeMillis();
        RightPanel.timeElapsedTextField.setText("");
        timer.start();
        startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }
```

In the `stop` method,

```
public void stop() {
        isStop=true;
        onPlay = false;
        if (piece != null) 
            piece.isMoving = false;
        playItem.setEnabled(true);  
        rightPanel.setPlayButtonEnable(true);
        pauseItem.setEnabled(false); 
        rightPanel.setPauseButtonLabel(true);
        stopItem.setEnabled(false);   
        resumeItem.setEnabled(false);
        setBlockColorItem.setEnabled(true);
        setBGColorItem.setEnabled(true);
        rightPanel.setPause(false);
        rightPanel.setStop(false);
        reset();
        //time.stop();
        timer.stop();
        long delta = (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime)/10;
        RightPanel.timeElapsedTextField.setText(Double.toString(delta/100.0) + " seconds");

    }
```

Are those enough? Whenever  try to display the time elapsed, the JTextField displays nothing. What can be wrong? Thank you very much!

```
public void run() {
            int column = 4, style = Piece.SHAPES[(int) (Math.random() * 7)][(int) (Math.random() * 4)];
            //timer.start();
            //startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            while (onPlay) {

                if (piece != null) {
                    if (piece.isAlive()) {
                        try {
                            Thread.currentThread().sleep(100);
                        } 
                        catch (InterruptedException ie) {
                            ie.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        continue;
                    }
                }

                checkFullLine();  
                if (isGameOver()) {
                    playItem.setEnabled(true);
                    pauseItem.setEnabled(true);
                    resumeItem.setEnabled(false);
                    rightPanel.setPlayButtonEnable(true);
                    rightPanel.setPauseButtonLabel(true);

                    displayGameOver();
                    return;
                }
                piece = new Piece(style, -1, column, board);
                piece.start();
                //numDropped = numDropped+1;
                //RightPanel.scoreTextField.setText(numDropped+"");
                style = Piece.SHAPES[(int) (Math.random() * 7)][(int) (Math.random() * 4)];
                rightPanel.setTipStyle(style);
                numDropped = numDropped+1;
                RightPanel.numDroppedTextField.setText(numDropped+"");
                //RightPanel.numDroppedTextField = new JTextField(numDropped+"");
                long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            }
            long estimatedTime = ((System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime)/1000);
            RightPanel.timeElapsedTextField.setText(estimatedTime+"");
        }
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Add validate() on the frame after you called setText

Comment: I added `validate()` just after `RightPanel.timeElapsedTextField.setText(Double.toString(delta/100.0) + " seconds");` but it still doesn't work. By the way, sir, what do you mean by frame? Thank you! @D3mon-1stVFW

Comment: I meant to refresh the swing container to show the changes by calling validate.  Just find where 'RightPanel' exists and call validate on the panel/frame.  Like Andrew Thompson said, this is just a guess.

Answer (score 2):

You should use [nanoTime()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#nanoTime%28%29) to calculate elapsed time.

```
long startTime = System.nanoTime();
// ... the code being measured ...
long estimatedTime = System.nanoTime() - startTime;
```

You have a Thread running for Game. I think you should calculate startTime in start of run() method and estimatedTime  end of run() method. I can only speculate since I don't know Game class code.

Below is the simple illustration of how you can do it.

```
  import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

  public class Demo implements Runnable {

private volatile boolean shouldRun = true;

@Override
public void run() {
    long startTime = System.nanoTime();
    while (shouldRun) {
        // do nothing
    }
    long estimatedTime = System.nanoTime() - startTime;
    System.out.println(TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS.toSeconds(estimatedTime));//Print apprx 5 seconds since time may be required to actually enter in to run method after start
}

public void stop() {
    shouldRun = false;
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    Demo demo = new Demo();
    Thread thread = new Thread(demo);
    thread.start();
    Thread.sleep(5000);// 5 Seconds sleep
    demo.stop();// Stop the thread
}
}
```

Comment: Pretty much this, take absolute timestamps, avoid relative/inaccurate measures such as `Thread.sleep()`.

Comment: I tried putting `long startTime = System.nanoTime();` in the `play()` method and `long estimatedTime = System.nanoTime() - startTime;` in the `stop()` method but it still does not show. What can be the correct implementation, sir?

Comment: I tried it in `run()` but the output is different from the real time elapsed. I included the code there above. :)

Comment: Even so. When the time elapsed is 5 seconds, it still display 1387890 something. :)

Comment: @SugarSpice I have added more illustrative example. Please check

Comment: Wow thank you! It works. One thing I wasn't able to do is to put `shouldRun = false;` in `stop()`. I tried. `Game.shouldrun` but it says there that it should be static but when it just generates another errors. With that, I cannot pause the time in the `pause()` method as well. How can I work on that sir? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

```
Duration
.between(
    then , 
    Instant.now()
)
.toSeconds()
```

## Details

`Timer` does not measure elapsed time.

Your calls to `System.currentTimeMillis` measure elapsed time. But that method is obsolete with Java 8 and later. Instead, use `java.time.Instant`.

`Instant` represents a moment in UTC with a resolution of nanoseconds. However, the hardware clocks in current conventional computers do not track time that accurately, so `Instant.now` captures the current moment with a resolution of microseconds in Java 9 and later (and milliseconds in Java 8 only).

```
Instant start = Instant.now() ; 
…
Instant stop = Instant.now() ;
```

To represent the time elapsed between those two moments, use [`Duration`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Duration.html).

```
Duration d = Duration.between( start , stop ) ;
```

Generate text in standard ISO 8601 for that elapsed time.

```
String output = d.toString() ;
```

Or interrogate for a count of seconds or some such.

```
long secondsElapsed = d.toSeconds() ;
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).